# Relationship must be key/value pair

Tags: ember.js, firebase

Getting the following error:

```
firebase.js:119 Uncaught Error: thunder@model:provider: relationship hasMany('address') must be a key/value map. Example: { "address": { "address_1": true } } instead got: "-KDehK2aAE15KEQXjHC-"
```

I have tried so many different ways and I am just getting so lost. I know I am missing something simple, just not sure where

Address Model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  city: DS.attr('string'),
  state: DS.attr('string'),
  street: DS.attr('string'),
  zip: DS.attr('string'),
  provider: DS.belongsTo('provider')
});
```

Provider Model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  category: DS.attr('string'),
  status: DS.attr('boolean'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.hasMany('address', {async: true}),
  phone: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr()
});
```

Here is what I have in Firebase

```
{
  "addresses" : {
    "-KDfELHB6F7_-luBeGpb" : {
      "city" : "King of Prussia",
      "state" : "PA",
      "street" : "135 Main Street",
      "zip" : "19406"
    }
  },
  "providers" : {
    "-KDfEQdjZm8uhOUMkRg3" : {
      "address" : "-KDfELHB6F7_-luBeGpb",
      "category" : "Tutoring",
      "description" : "Apple Uber UI Full stack guy",
      "email" : "johnservice@test.com",
      "name" : "John's Services",
      "phone" : "215-555-9999",
      "status" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated with the json code

Comment: If i read the error correct you are only sending the key of the object instead of the entire object.